# Unregistered Web context in Jboss

Tags: spring, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

Whenever I try to run a spring app in wildfly server, it gets deployed succefully but within a instance it gets undeployed. Here is the log:

```
13:00:28,442 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1027 ms
13:00:28,445 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
13:00:28,445 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
13:00:28,447 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 17 13:00:28 NPT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:00:28,447 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
13:00:28,462 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 17 ms
13:00:28,462 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /taml-nbl
13:00:28,494 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "taml-nbl.war" (runtime-name : "taml-nbl.war")
13:00:30,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-21) BfiDAOImplementation:bfiLogo method invoked.
13:00:33,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = taml-nbl.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_4
13:00:33,538 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /taml-nbl
13:00:33,542 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
13:00:33,542 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 17 13:00:28 NPT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:00:33,546 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13:00:33,546 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jul 17 13:00:27 NPT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
13:00:33,547 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
13:00:33,550 INFO  [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Stopping...
13:00:33,552 INFO  [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=false, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
13:00:33,553 INFO  [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Stopped.
13:00:33,555 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Shutting down ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
13:00:33,564 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Shutting down ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
13:00:33,565 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
13:00:33,565 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
13:00:33,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment taml-nbl.war (runtime-name: taml-nbl.war) in 67ms
13:00:33,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "taml-nbl.war" (runtime-name: "taml-nbl.war")
13:00:38,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDS0004: Found taml-nbl.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called taml-nbl.war.dodeploy
```

Even If I manually add .dodeploy file in deployment directory, its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I know am late to this party but just wanted to post as there were no answers for this.

I was facing this issue and all i did was,

Cleared everything which was in jboss-tmp folder and boom it worked.